# Event propagation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of click events which are causing me some propagation issues. The data for this container is loaded in via ajax hence the body on click method. Here's the code I have:

```js
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click","#top-div",function(){
        console.log("top event");
    });

    $("body").on("click","#middle-div",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body").on("click","#bottom-div",function(){
        console.log("bottom event");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-div">
  top
    <div id="middle-div">
      middle
        <div id="bottom-div">
          bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The top div has an event which the middle one needs to not inherit hence the `stopPropagation()`. However the bottom one needs to have an event of its own but the `stopPropagation()` from the middle one is stopping it from executing the event (if I remove the stop propagation the bottom event triggers but coincidentally so does the top)

How can I get around this bubbling issue?

Comment: Can you unnest the divs?

Comment: just return early if validating `event.target` fails, which is good delegation anyway

Comment: Your description is confusing. The `stopPropagation` doesn't prevent the "bottom" handler; it prevents the "top" handler. There's nothing right now that prevents a click from invoking the "bottom" handler.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. When I click on `bottom` I see the message `bottom event`. What's supposed to happen in stead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you want to happen is that the propagation is only stopped if it originated from the middle `div`; if it originated from the bottom `div` you want the event to bubble all the way to the top.

You need to call `stopPropagation` conditionally. If the event did not originate on or inside `#bottom-div`, you want to call it. You can test for this using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
if (!$(e.target).closest('#bottom-div').length) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

It is better to use `closest` for this, rather than testing the element's `id` directly, because with `closest` it will continue to work as expected even if there are other elements (`a` or `em`, for example) within the various `div`s.

```js
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click","#top-div",function(){
        console.log("top event");
    });

    $("body").on("click","#middle-div",function(e){
        if (!$(e.target).closest('#bottom-div').length) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });

    $("body").on("click","#bottom-div",function(){
        console.log("bottom event");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-div">
  top
    <div id="middle-div">
      middle
        <div id="bottom-div">
          bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really have no idea what the OP is asking, but part of the complaint seems to be that if the `stopPropagation` is removed, both the bottom and top get invoked. So this seems to do what is trying to be prevented, but again, the question is very unclear, IMO.

Comment: @squint Yes, hence the italicised *think* in the first line! Looking at the code, this seemed to be the obvious potential issue.

Comment: @squint Though, honestly, it's probably the HTML that needs fixing, not the JS.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that line. I'm just saying that your interpretation doesn't seem to line up with the information provided. But given the description of the issue, I can't say you're wrong either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching event to every div. You can consider doing it as follows
check this snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", "div", function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id + "event");
    if (event.target.id === "middle-div") {
      event.stopPropagation()
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-div">
  hello
  <div id="middle-div">
    hi
    <div id="bottom-div">
      bott-mid-v
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The OP is using event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Bubbling works from most nested element to tree root, I think You misunderstanding it in some way. So for example click in **bottom-div** will:

call event on **bottom-div** --> call event on **middle-div** --> call event on **top-div**.

As I understand the need You want to some how check what div was clicked, so to have control on it just create single event and check clicked target like that:

```
$("body").on("click","#top-div",function(e){

   if ( e.target.id ==='top-div'){
     //click in top div
   }

   if ( e.target.id ==='middle-div'){
     //click in middle div
   }

   if ( e.target.id ==='bottom-div'){
     //click in bottom div
   }



});
```

In this proposition You know exactly which div was clicked, but it will always be the most nested one, so target will be **middle-div** only when will be clicked part of **middle-div** which is not **bottom-div**, it will be for example padding space, the same is with **top-div** it will be target only if click will be in space without child elements.

More about event bubbling You can find in http://maciejsikora.com/standard-events-vs-event-delegation/.