# Stop propagation on parent div, when children are bound through $(body)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container `<div>` that has dynamically appended divs. The divs are given `click` handles through the `body` element, like this: `$(body).on("click",".divClass",function);` (I did it this way so that the bindings on the dynamically added elements can be done all in one place in the code, and to prevent tons of bindings). I need to put a `stopPropagation()` on the container div, so that the click handle on its parent doesn't get triggered. The problem is, when I put in the `stopPropagation` on the container div, it stops the child div from triggering (since it is actually the body that has the binding, not the child div)

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates my problem:

```js
$("#A").click(function() {

  console.log('This event should not fire when clicking innermost')

});

$("#B").click(function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();

});

$("body").on("click", "#C", function() {

  console.log('This event should fire when clicking innermost')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
  outermost&nbsp;
  <div id="B">
    middle&nbsp;
    <div id="C">
      innermost
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [A bizarrely similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598293/event-propagation-issue/41598470)

Comment: @lonesomeday woah..... I swear I didn't look at their snippet, but that is eerily similar to my snippet. The bindings are a little different in the parent divs in my question, however.

Comment: Your event handler for #C will happen after B and A have occured. There's nothing you can do short of not using event delegation or not stopping propagation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the other children to propagate as normal, only the children in
>   `#B` should not propagate.

Taking this into account, your original code wasn't too far off. Seeing you are binding directly to `#B` in your example, I assume `#B` is static.

In that case use `#B` as the static reference instead of `body`.

```js
$("#A").click(function(e) {
  console.log('This event should not fire when clicking innermost')
});

$("#B").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#B").on("click", "#C", function(e) {
    console.log('This event should fire when clicking innermost')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
  outermost&nbsp;
  <div id="B">
    middle&nbsp;
    <div id="C">
      innermost
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if a child of `#A` other than `#B` is clicked in case there is any other child

Comment: yes, in my case, #A does have other children, so unfortunately this won't work for me. (I want the other children to propagate as normal, only the children in #B should not propagate)

Comment: @PranavCBalan The code in `#A` only executes when `#A` is clicked and ignores all children.

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly Have you tested the code? `#A` can have as many children as it wants to, it ignores all their events and only works when `#A` is clicked or is that not what you want?

Comment: I want the other children to propagate as normal, only the children in #B should not propagate.

Comment: I'm assuming `#B` is not dynamically added as your example code binds directly to it....in that case use that as the closest static parent instead of `body`

Comment: `e.target === this` is unlikely to be a useful test if the dynamically added elements have child elements. `$(e.target).closest(this).length` is the better way to go.

Comment: @lonesomeday As I said in the above comment, now that OP clarified that other children can exist then binding to `#B` instead `body` is enough but yes, `$(e.target).closest(this).length` is better assuming there is more children.

Answer (score 2):

I think this whole problem would be much simpler if you bound the delegated handler to `#B` in the first place. Then the events don't need to bubble up to the `body` and `stopPropagation` will have the desired effect.

```js
$("#A").click(function() {
  console.log('This event should not fire when clicking innermost')
});

$("#B").on("click", "#C", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('This event should fire when clicking innermost')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A">
  outermost&nbsp;
  <div id="B">
    middle&nbsp;
    <div id="C">
      innermost
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```